# Keep SEO URL but send the id from the database

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having some troubles with the .htaccess and SEO URL (aka URL rewrite). For instance I have a list of categories like (extracted from the database) :

```
id   name
1    category template
2    category-template
3    category template
4    category-template
```

I have some duplicate names, and judging by the lowercase and replacing spaces with "-" in the url I have all the fields from the database resulting in the same format (lowercase and replace " " with "-").

My actual .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Is there some way that I can generate a url like `www.website.com/category-template` and by clicking on that the next script will get through `$_POST` variable the id from the database (for instance: 3)? I have 4 "identical" rewrites but each with a distinct id in the database and I want to retrieve the id of the correct one.

Thank you!

LE: I want to keep the URL very clean, like `www.website.com/category-template`, although there is a simpler way of doing it by inserting the id like: `www.website.com/id/category-template` or `www.website.com/category-template-[+id]`.

Comment: You could do a query at the script run at `www.website.com/category-template` that pulls the data based on the slug (category-template). That seems like the best way to handle it.

Comment: Through the $_POST variable I would get 'category-template' because of the url format: `www.website.com/category-template`. The idea is that even if I decode the result, there are duplicate names. I want to send the id (without showing it in the url) so that I can retrieve the correct record from the database.

Comment: Adding an id to a SEO url isn't going to hurt you (SEO wise) and is much better usability wise that requiring POST data to get to a page when it's not needed.

Comment: Why not edit the URL slightly to be more along the lines of `www.website.com/category-template/this-one` (`this-one` being an id or, for prettier urls, some sort of slug)?

Comment: 1. Users do not care about id's in URL's. They come to look at your site not your links and they bookmark what they want. 2. It's not going to hurt your SEO at all. Look up. There is a question ID in every Stackoverflow question and they are usually the first to show up in a Google search. **So.... don't over complicate it for no reason**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change URL e.g. to switch to

```
www.website.com/{category_id}/{category-title} or
www.website.com/{category-title}/{category_id}
```

e.g.

```
www.website.com/3/category-template or
www.website.com/category-template/3
```